# Index out of bounds exception: getting same row repeated several times

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my code which I use to take in an Excel sheet, read its contents and to each row I add a GUID from a list I have.

**UPDATE**
Code:

```
public class PublishOutputFile {

    public void publishOutputWithGuids(List<String> guids, File file)
            throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileStream);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row toprow = sheet.getRow(0);
        int cellsNum = toprow.getLastCellNum();
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            int rownum = row.getRowNum();
            System.out.println(rownum);
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    break;
                }
                if (rownum == 0) {
                    row.createCell(cellsNum).setCellValue("GUID");
                } else {
//                  System.out.println(rownum);
                    row.createCell(cellsNum).setCellValue(guids.get(rownum-1));
                }
            }
        }
        fileStream.close();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                new File(
                        "C:/Users/U0172959/Desktop/Themes_20131120_234645-hierarchy with GUIDS.xls"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
140
141
142
143
144
145
146
147
148
149
150
151
152
153
154
155
156
157
158
159
160
161
162
163
164
165
166
167
168
169
170
171
172
173
174
175
176
177
178
179
180
181
182
183
184
185
186
187
188
189
190
191
192
193
194
195
196
197
198
199
200
201
202
203
204
205
206
207
208
209
210
211
212
213
214
215
216
217
218
219
220
221
222
223
224
225
226
227
228
229
230
231
232
233
234
235
236
237
238
239
240
241
242
243
244
245
246
247
248
249
250
251
252
253
254
255
256
257
258
259
260
261
262
263
264
265
266
267
268
269
270
271
272
273
274
275
276
277
278
279
280
281
282
283
284
285
286
287
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 286, Size: 286
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at mappingForEtl.PublishOutputFile.publishOutputWithGuids(PublishOutputFile.java:43)
    at mappingForEtl.InputFileParsing.main(InputFileParsing.java:75)
```

In the output, every row is being repeated like 5 times and I think this is what causes the out of bounds exception. But I can't figure out what's causing this to happen.

(I have used the same code for a different file yesterday, and that worked fine... ) Can it have anything to do with the number of columns in the excel sheet I take as input. The one I used yesterday had 8 columns, the one I am using now has 20.

Anyone has any idea what might be causing this? Thanks for help.

Comment: Why are you iterating over each Cell on each Row and creating the same  GUID column?

Comment: Do you have guids reference refering to a list of expecting size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the cells within a row and for each cell you print the row number. Are you very sure that the data you print the right values in your `else` case?

```
if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
    row.createCell(cellsNum).setCellValue("GUID");
} else {
    System.out.println((row.getRowNum())); // row number for each cell?
    row.createCell(cellsNum).setCellValue(guids.get((row.getRowNum())));
}
```

Update:

The problem with the repeated output is that you have a loop over your rows. Each row consists of a number of cells. You loop over the cells as well. The repeated output comes from the fact, that while you loop through the cells in the row, the row does not change.
For better understanding, you should change your output to that:

```
System.out.println("Being at row: " + row.getRowNum() + " creating cell at cellnum: " + cellsNum);
```

That should clean up the understanding of what is going on.

Update 2:

The IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown because the size of guid is 286 but the index is zero based and does not start by 1. As you tread the first row different, you should change `guids.get(row.getRowNum())` to `guids.get(row.getRowNum() - 1)`. That can work but it does not have to. As long as we don't know the detailed data structure, it might be of no value for you...

Comment: In fact, the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` comes from `ArrayList` (the line below), not from the `System.out.println`...

Comment: Glad that I haven't mentioned the IndexOutOfBoundsException with a single word. My answer focuses on the 5 times repeated output. Thanks for pointing on something unrelated to my answer. Feel free to upvote, downvote or dance around...

Comment: `row.getRowNum()` is returning the same row 5 times. That's what is confusing me. And I can't figure out what's causing this

Comment: @DT7 I updated my answer and tried to explain it in more detail

Comment: @WarrenFaith I will try this.. Hopefully that helps

Comment: @DT7 it will not fix your Exception but it should tell you why you have the same row repeated 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

**About the Exception**

You may have accidentaly created some new `Row` (*probably blank*) and there is no `GUID` on your `List` for that `Row`. That could cause this Exception.

Maybe this addition helps you:

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    if (row.getLastCellNum() < cellsNum)
        continue;
```

**About the repeated output**

You are iterating over each row, and then iterating over each cell, and then printing the row number. Considering a row has 4 cells, this would end up printing the Row number 4 times.

Comment: EDIT: Addressing the two problems mentioned by the OP

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:

```java
} else {
    row.createCell(cellsNum).setCellValue(
        guids.get((row.getRowNum())));
}
```

Your `guids.get` is throwing the exception since it doesn't contain an element at index 286.

Solution: retrieve the element at index in `row.getRowNum - 1`, so you will now retrieve elements from 0 to 285:

```java
} else {
    row.createCell(cellsNum).setCellValue(
        guids.get((row.getRowNum() - 1)));
}
```

Update:

Since it looks you're not trying to solve the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (very odd) but more about why the numbers are printed 4 to 5 times, then review your current algorithm:

```java
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
//verify if there's a row to read in the current Excel sheet
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    //get the row
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    //get an iterator of the cells
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    //while there's a cell to read...
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        //get the cell
        //note: if the cell is empty, it won't be considered by the CellIterator, so even
        //if you open the file and see 20 cells, this Iterator will seek for cells with some value
        //from your current output, this looks to be only 5 cells
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        //verify the type of the cell...
        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            //do nothing?
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            //do nothing?
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            //do nothing?
            break;
        }
        if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
            row.createCell(cellsNum).setCellValue("GUID");
        } else {
            //prints the number of the row (per cell)
            //this causes the 1\n1\n1\n1\n2\n2\n... output
            System.out.println((row.getRowNum()));
            //writes the element in guids at index of row num
            row.createCell(cellsNum).setCellValue(
                    //guids.get((row.getRowNum())));
                    guids.get((row.getRowNum() - 1)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I figured that.. But as I mentioned it is happening because somehow `row.getRowNum()` is returning the same row 5 times. That's what is confusing me.

Comment: @DT7 that's not the problem. Note that the console output is very explicit about this: first, it prints 286 (from `System.out.println((row.getRowNum()));`) then comes the Exception. By the way, you're getting the same row printed 5 times since you're navigating through the cells in the row, which seems to be 5.

Comment: `System.out.println(guids.size());` is what prints 286 , because that's the size of my list that's passed on to the method. And the number of cells in sheet is 20

Comment: @DT7 answer updated, with an explanation and a real solution of the problem.

Comment: I updated my code to use row.getRowNum()-1, but it still gives the same exception.

Comment: @DT7 update the question and add (at the bottom) the new code that gives you problems.